# iFrame PHP page checking source (referrer) of the call

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

Can anyone tell me how Facebook Like identifies the page domain of where the iFrame is placed?

Reason I am asking is say I have an iFrame in http://www.firstdomain.com that loads a http://www.mysite.com/page.php?appid=111&userid=5". I only want http://www.firstdomain.com to be allowed to view that page, but if some other domain name (http://www.anotherwebsite.com) tries to put the same iFrame, it should not work.

Any thoughts? How to make this in PHP/JavaScript and be secure at the same time. I am trying to avoid using Proxy Pages on the server requesting the page.. just pure Javascript and iFrame.. any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put a js in client pages that generates the iframe in the dom, passing as parameter to the src page the url of "hosting" page, and so the domain.

Like this:

```
<script src="http://example.com/ilikeapp.js" />
```

Where ilikeapp is something like (almost pseudo code):

```
    var hosting_page = window.location;
    $(body).append("<iframe src='http://example.com/apage.php?client="+hosting_page+"' .... />");
```